# How to delete the preview icon of a PNG file with AppleScript or the Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I am trying to automatically delete the preview icon of a PNG file (or many files) that I have generated with Photoshop.

I know how to manually do this: I can select the files, hit command+shift+i, select the icon on that window and hit the delete key to delete the files; but I would prefer to do this automatically with an AppleScript (or a Terminal command that I will then embed in my AppleScript with a `do shell` command)... I have searched the web for days but I have found nothing that helps me.

So, does anyone know of an AppleScript or Terminal command that could be used to delete the preview icon of a PNG (or JPEG) file?

Comment: What do you mean by `Preview icon`? What characterises this file - its size maybe? How do you select these rather than other files? Do they have a different extension or something?

Comment: Hi Mark! A preview icon is a legacy thing, from earlier versions of Mac OS, back when the Finder didn't automatically generate a preview of an image file. It is a resource stored inside a file that makes its size bigger. If you create a file with Photoshop (for example) and then you delete its icon in the Finder (by showing info on the file, selecting its icon and hitting the "delete" key) then you'll see that the file size shrinks, the icon changes momentarily to a generic PNG icon and then the Finder generates a preview but your file still has the lower size... I was talking about that icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setIcon` method from the `NSWorkspace` class to delete icon of the file. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/

---

A **Cocoa-AppleScript Applet**

```
use framework "AppKit"
use scripting additions
set myFiles to choose file with prompt "Select PNG files" with multiple selections allowed
set sharedWk to current application's NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace()
repeat with tFile in myFiles
    (sharedWk's setIcon:(missing value) forFile:(POSIX path of tFile) options:0)
end repeat
```

---

Or an AppleScript using a **do shell script**

```
set pyScript to quoted form of "from AppKit import NSWorkspace; import sys; NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().setIcon_forFile_options_(None, sys.argv[1].decode('utf-8'), 0)"
set myFiles to choose file with prompt "Select PNG files" with multiple selections allowed
repeat with tFile in myFiles
    do shell script "/usr/bin/python -c " & pyScript & " " & (quoted form of POSIX path of tFile)
end repeat
```

---

Here's some links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_(API)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ScriptingAutomation/RN-AppleScriptObjC/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyObjC

JavaScript with Objective-C Bridge --> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!! How did you find this solution? As I said in my question, I've being looking for something like this for many days!! (I used your Cocoa-AppleScript Applet) Thank you sooo much!!!

Comment: I use Cocoa (API) with the Objective-C language in Xcode for several years to create utilities and command line tools.

Or, I can use these frameworks in a python shell. 
On the recent OS, I can use these frameworks in the AppleScript language or in the javaScript language. 
It's not too complicated to convert Objective-C code to AppleScriptObjC. 
I adding some links in my answer.

Comment: Well, then thank you again so much for sharing your knowledge of many years. You have certainly taught me something I didn't know that was possible to do. :)